# How to give blocks a meaningful name in the views overview page?

Tags: views, 8

I think, the image will speak for itself:

[image]

I have tried the block & display titles, the block name & also the new administrative comment field. Still the views overview looks not very informative.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe there is sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, there's no way to add a description for views displays for better visual distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Currently your description is empty, you can add a description to your view which will help somewhat.

Click on the <kbd>edit view name/description</kbd> button

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the view itself doesn't need too much description, it's rather the displays.